# Problemas de vistas en Django TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, template, django-templates

Soy nuevo en esto de Stack overflow así que díganme si falta alguna info importante. Tengo un problema con mi aplicación de Django

me tira este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son algunos fragmentos del código

Clase/Views:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
class ListaUsuarios(ListView):
model = Usuario
template_name = "usuario_list.html"
```

Clase/Urls:

```
    from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('Formulario/', views.formulario_usuario, name="Formulario"),
    path('Publicaciones/', views.formulario_publicacion, name="Publicaciones"),
    path('Comentarios/', views.formulario_comentario, name="Comentarios"), 
    path('usuarios/', views.lista_usuarios , name="lista_usuarios"),
    # CRUD publicaciones
    path('publicacion/listado', views.publicacion_listado, name="publicacion_listado"),
    path('publicacion/crear', views.crear_publicacion, name="crear_publicacion"),
    path('publicacion/borrar/<int:id>', views.borrar_publicacion, name="borrar_publicacion"),
    path('publicacion/leer', views.leer_publicacion, name="leer_publicacion"),
    path('publicacion/update/<int:id>', views.update_publicacion, name="update_publicacion"),
    # CRUD Usuarios CBV 
    path('usuarios/list', views.ListaUsuarios.as_view(), name="usuario_list"),
]
```

Clase/templates/form/usuario_list.html

```
{% extends 'index\index.html' %}

{% block Encabezado %}
<h1>Busca a otros usuarios en Landfy</h1>
<span class="subheading">Encuentra a tus amigos en Landfy en nuestra base de datos</span>
{% endblock Encabezado %}


{% block Formulario %}

<p> Todos los usuarios:</p>
{% for usuario in object_list %}
<li>
    {{usuario}}
</li>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock Formulario %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu settings.py esta configurado para que busque en las carpetas templates incluidas las de las apps entonces el error esta en tu ListView, tu template esta en form/usuario_list.html

La manera correcta de ponerlo en tu vista es así:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
class ListaUsuarios(ListView):
    model = Usuario
    template_name = "form/usuario_list.html"
```

Comment: Hace una semana estoy con este problema, te besaria las manos si te tuviera en frente. Mil millones de Gracias :,D

Comment: @ErnestoCampos recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta si solucionó tu problema :D